# T-SQL Trigger - Updating a Table using a separate table, multi-row insert possible

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm new to triggers and am working on setting up a trigger to update a table (`REQ_L`) when a record is inserted there that meets specific parameters.  The value to update in `REQ_L` is pulled from a separate table that has a matching key.

```
create table REQ_L (item_number varchar(20), 
                    commodity_code varchar(20), 
                    vendor_id varchar(20), 
                    item_source varchar(20));

create table XREF_C (item_number varchar(20), 
                     commodity_code varchar(20), 
                     xref_type varchar(20));
```

I'd like it for when a record is inserted into `REQ_L`, if it meets the criteria in the trigger it will be update the `COMMODITY_CODE` from `REQ_L` with the `COMMODITY_CODE` in `XREF_C` using the `ITEM_NUMBER` as the key.

No longer locking and switched over to using the inserted tables.  The good news is no more deadlock, the bad is that it's still not updating the table. Updated SQL Trigger attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER WBM
    ON REQ_L
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE VENDOR_ID = 'W7315'
                AND ITEM_SOURCE = 'XML'
                AND COMMODITY_CODE NOT LIKE '%-%')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE REQ_L
            SET COMMODITY_CODE = (SELECT distinct CODE_2 
                                    FROM XREF_C xc, inserted i 
                                    WHERE i.ITEM_NUMBER = xc.CODE_1 
                                    AND xc.XREF_TYPE = 'WBM')
        FROM XREF_C xc, inserted i
        WHERE i.ITEM_NUMBER = xc.CODE_1
        END
GO
```

Comment: First, I assume by 'locking' you mean deadlocking? Second, `FROM XREF_C xc, REQ_L rl` is ancient, ancient syntax. You should be using the ISO standard JOIN syntax. Support for this old syntax will disappear at some point. However, the most important thing is that you need to read up on triggers and the `INSERTED` pseudotable. You are attempting to update the entire `REQ_L` table here, and this is almost certainly where you are deadlocking.

Comment: An `INSERT` trigger usually references the `inserted` table.  In this case you would probably want to restrict your search to rows just inserted into `REQ_L`.  Is there also an `UPDATE` trigger on `REQ_L`?  Recursive triggers can get nasty.

Comment: @DeanGC, yes it's deadlocking.
HABO I had read about the 'inserted' table but wasn't entirely sure what they referenced. There are no recursive triggers on this table.

Comment: @DeanGC, thanks for the info.  I'll switch to JOIN.  I'll research the inserted table further.

Comment: @HABO I updated to reflect using the inserted table.  I'm still working on the join.  Do I need to put in a commit?

Comment: No, this will run as part of the transaction doing the UPDATE, and will COMMIT/ROLLBACK with it.

Comment: Where in hell are CODE_1 and CODE_2 fields coming from - they are in neither table?

Answer (score 0):

Try simplyfing your query structure. I still don't know what CODE_1 and CODE_2 are but this worked for me.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[WBM]
    ON [dbo].[REQ_L]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    UPDATE  REQ_L
    SET     commodity_code = xc.commodity_code  FROM    INSERTED i          INNER JOIN          XREF_C xc ON i.Item_Number=xc.item_number
                         AND
                         xc.xref_type = 'WBM'
                         AND
                         i.VENDOR_ID = 'W7315'
                         AND
                         i.ITEM_SOURCE = 'XML'
                         AND
                         i.COMMODITY_CODE NOT LIKE '%-%'
```

Remember, `IF` statements belong in C# and Visual Basic - if you are using them in SQL you are not writing your queries with a dataset mentality. Most of the time that is; sometimes they can't be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the general comments above, but I'm thinking the logic your using looks dodgy. You have:

```
    UPDATE REQ_L
        SET COMMODITY_CODE = (SELECT distinct CODE_2 
                                FROM XREF_C xc, inserted i 
                                WHERE i.ITEM_NUMBER = xc.CODE_1 
                                AND xc.XREF_TYPE = 'WBM')
    FROM XREF_C xc, inserted i
    WHERE i.ITEM_NUMBER = xc.CODE_1
```

Well I may be wrong, but I can't help thinking that the table you're updating should appear in the from clause of the statement.

How about this:

```
UPDATE rl
SET Commodity_Code = x.Code_2
FROM Req_L rl
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON --limit the join clause to the cols that have been inserted
        rl.item_number = i.item_number and  
        rl.commodity_code = i.commodity_code and
        rl.vendor_id = i.vendor_id and 
        rl.item_source = i.item_source
    INNER JOIN XREF_C x ON L.item_number = x.item_number
WHERE x.xref_type = 'WBM'
```